Rust error E0432, E0061, E0308 From Solana Bot
I am having trouble with my code, I keep getting these errors
error[E0432]: unresolved import `solana_rpc_client::rpc_config`
 --> src/main.rs:2:24
  |
2 | use solana_rpc_client::rpc_config::RpcTransactionConfig;
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `rpc_config` in `solana_rpc_client`

error[E0061]: this method takes 1 argument but 2 arguments were supplied
    --> src/main.rs:26:39
     |
26   |         let signatures = match client.get_signatures_for_address(&target_wallet, None) {
     |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 ---- unexpected argument #2 of type `Option<_>`
     |
note: method defined here
    --> C:\Users\geowa\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\solana-rpc-client-1.18.26\src\rpc_client.rs:2463:12
     |
2463 |     pub fn get_signatures_for_address(
     |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: remove the extra argument
     |
26   -         let signatures = match client.get_signatures_for_address(&target_wallet, None) {
26   +         let signatures = match client.get_signatures_for_address(&target_wallet) {
     |

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:101:9
    |
100 |     match Keypair::from_base58_string(base58_key) {
    |           --------------------------------------- this expression has type `Keypair`
101 |         Ok(keypair) => Ok(keypair),
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Keypair`, found `Result<_, _>`
    |
    = note: expected struct `Keypair`
                 found enum `Result<_, _>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:101:9
    |
100 |     match Keypair::from_base58_string(base58_key) {
    |           --------------------------------------- this expression has type `Keypair`
101 |         Ok(keypair) => Ok(keypair),
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Keypair`, found `Result<_, _>`
    |
    = note: expected struct `Keypair`
                 found enum `Result<_, _>`

that I have no idea how to resolve, don't code much at all and to be honest used AI a lot so dont really know what I'm doing just making this for myself. I used alchemy for the API and made the wallet.json with solana cli. Thanks
use solana_rpc_client::rpc_client::RpcClient;
use solana_rpc_client::rpc_config::RpcTransactionConfig;
use solana_sdk::{
    signature::{Keypair, read_keypair_file, Signer},
    transaction::Transaction,
    instruction::Instruction,
    pubkey::Pubkey
};
use std::{thread::sleep, time::Duration};

fn main() {
    // Load the private key from the file
    let my_wallet_private_key = read_keypair_file("./my_wallet.json")
        .expect("Failed to read wallet keypair");

    let my_wallet_pubkey = my_wallet_private_key.pubkey();
    println!("My wallet public key: {:?}", my_wallet_pubkey);

    let client = RpcClient::new("https://solana-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/MKFMDpQKd5PBG0QWKkObEUE_76leKphx");

    let target_wallet: Pubkey = "5KezperZs8nPLaq66Nghembf7ADk1S47JeTZqaX9p9BS".parse().unwrap();
    println!("Monitoring transactions for wallet: {}", target_wallet);

    loop {
        // Fetch the latest confirmed signatures for the target wallet
        let signatures = match client.get_signatures_for_address(&target_wallet, None) {
            Ok(sigs) => sigs,
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("Failed to fetch signatures: {}", e);
                continue;
            }
        };

        for signature_info in signatures.iter() {
            let signature = match signature_info.signature.parse() {
                Ok(sig) => sig,
                Err(e) => {
                    eprintln!("Failed to parse signature: {}", e);
                    continue;
                }
            };

            // Fetch transaction details with max supported version
            let tx_details = match client.get_transaction_with_config(
                &signature,
                RpcTransactionConfig {
                    max_supported_transaction_version: Some(0), // Ensure compatible version
                    ..Default::default()
                },
            ) {
                Ok(tx) => tx,
                Err(e) => {
                    eprintln!("Failed to fetch transaction details: {}", e);
                    continue;
                }
            };

            if let Some(meta) = tx_details.transaction.meta {
                println!("Transaction meta: {:?}", meta);

                // Construct instructions for the new transaction
                let instructions: Vec<Instruction> = meta
                    .post_balances
                    .iter()
                    .map(|balance| Instruction {
                        program_id: target_wallet,
                        accounts: vec![], // Add required accounts
                        data: vec![*balance as u8], // Ensure data is packed correctly
                    })
                    .collect();

                let blockhash = match client.get_latest_blockhash() {
                    Ok(hash) => hash,
                    Err(e) => {
                        eprintln!("Failed to fetch latest blockhash: {}", e);
                        continue;
                    }
                };

                let new_tx = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
                    &instructions,
                    Some(&my_wallet_pubkey),
                    &[&my_wallet_private_key],
                    blockhash,
                );

                match client.send_transaction(&new_tx) {
                    Ok(sig) => println!("Successfully copied trade with signature: {}", sig),
                    Err(e) => eprintln!("Failed to send transaction: {}", e),
                }
            }
        }

        // Delay to avoid excessive RPC calls
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    }
}

fn load_keypair_from_base58(base58_key: &str) -> Result<Keypair, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    match Keypair::from_base58_string(base58_key) {
        Ok(keypair) => Ok(keypair),
        Err(e) => Err(Box::new(e)),
    }
}

